# Build lists out of dictionary

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph

I've got a dictionary that for each **key** lists its dependencies:

```
parent[2] = 1 (2 depends on 1)
parent[3] = 1 (3 depends on 1)
parent[4] = {2,3} (4 depends on 2, or 4 depends on 3)
```

I want to build lists out of this dictionary:

```
[4,2,1]
[4,3,1]
```

I've got the suspicion I should use a recursive algorithm. Any hints?

**EDIT**: this is what I have so far:

How I call the recursive function:

```
var result = new List<List<Node<TData, TId>>>();
GetResult(parent, target, result);
return result;
```

And the recursive function itself:

```
private static List<Node<TData, TId>> GetResult<TData, TId>(Dictionary<Node<TData, TId>, List<Node<TData, TId>>> parent, Node<TData, TId> index,
    List<List<Node<TData, TId>>> finalList)
    where TData : IIdentifiable<TId>
    where TId : IComparable
{
    var newResult = new List<Node<TData, TId>> { index };

    if (parent.ContainsKey(index))
    {
        if (parent[index].Count == 1)
        {
            return new List<Node<TData, TId>> { index, parent[index].First()};
        }

        foreach (var child in parent[index])
        {
            var temp = newResult.Union(GetResult(parent, child, finalList)).ToList();
            finalList.Add(temp);
        }
    }

    return newResult;
}
```

Comment: Yup, it should be recursion. What is the problem you faced?

Comment: You're *almost* looking for a *topological sort* algorithm. *Almost* because your list means *OR* instead of *AND*. Is there any possibility of having *A depends on B and C*?

Comment: @Dmitry, I've edited the post to include my code. It doesn't work for the case in which `dict[4] = 1`, it should return just one list containing `[4,1]` but it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to adapt for your needs the following code:

```
public static List<List<int>> FindParents(Dictionary<int, List<int>> parents, int index)
{
    List<int> prefix = new List<int>();
    List<List<int>> results = new List<List<int>>();
    FindParentsInternal(parents, index, prefix, results);
    return results;
}

private static void FindParentsInternal(Dictionary<int, List<int>> parents, int index,
    List<int> prefix, List<List<int>> results)
{
    var newPrefix = new List<int>(prefix) { index };
    if (!parents.ContainsKey(index))
    {
        results.Add(newPrefix);
        return;
    }
    parents[index].ForEach(i => FindParentsInternal(parents, i, newPrefix, results));
}
```

Usage:

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> parents = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>
    {
        { 2, new List<int> { 1 } },
        { 3, new List<int> { 1 } },
        { 4, new List<int> { 2, 3 } }
    };

var t = FindParents(parents, 4);
```

Comment: What is the result of your try? I'm curious.

Comment: Hmm. On a later attempt with a large dictionary, I'm getting a Stack Overflow error.. Weird...

Comment: Maybe there are loops in the large dictionary. For instance, some element has itself in its parents. If so, you should handle this situation using `prefix.Contains(index)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can benefit by keeping a dictionary of results - that way you won't need to keep recomputing them.

```
Dictionary<Int, Set<Int>> results;

Set<Int> getResult(int index) {
  Set<Int> dictResult = results.get(index);
  if(dictResult != null) {
    // result has already been computed
    return dictResult;
  } else {
    // compute result, store in dictResult
    Set<Int> newResult = // compute dependency set
    dictResult.put(index, newResult);
    return newResult;
  }
}
```

As for the `// compute dependency list` part, you can do something like the following:

```
Set<Int> newResult = new Set(index);
if(dict.containsKey(index)) {
  List<Int> dependencies = dict.get(index);
  foreach(int subIndex in dependencies) {
    newResult = newResult.union(getResult(subIndex));
  }
}
```

Your base case is when the index is not in `dict` (i.e. `dict.containsKey` returns false), e.g. 1 for the data you provided.